# Sharepoint online recurring task list

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I want to create monthly recurring task list with due dates, each assigned to multiple users. The users should be able to access only their own tasks and update task outcome. How can I go about it?

Comment: Hi, do you want 1. new tasks to be added with due dates monthly or 2. it's kind of a automated processes where you create a task once with desired frequency and the system will send automated notifications based on the frequency. #1 can be easily achieved with SharePoint out-of-the-box workflows.

Answer (score 0):

You could create multiple approval workflows, and assign these workflows to multiple users separately.

Go to SharePoint Designer -> Create a 2013 workflow -> Add an action -> Start s task process -> As following picture shows.
[image]